# $c\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $cA$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> "Let $A$ a square matrix have an eigenvalue $\lambda$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$.  Let $c\in F$. Then $c\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $cA$."

This is true right? since the eigenvalues of $A$ form the eigenvectors in $A$, multiplying $A$ by a scalar $c$ is still equivalent to $A$, so their eigenvalues must be proportional too?

Comment: More concretely, simply show that there is an eigenvector of $cA$ with eigenvalue $c\lambda$...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is easy to check: we have $$(cA)v=c(Av)=c(\lambda v)=(c\lambda)v.$$ The first equality is by definition, the second by the assumption that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and the third equality is just the basic associativity property of scalar multiplication.